# Calculating DAU and MAU using Prometheus

Tags: analytics, prometheus

My task is to implement DAU and MAU metrics using Prometheus as data storage.

In order to do this I created counter `active_users`

```
Counter activeUsers = new Counter().build().name("active_users").labelNames("username").register();
```

And on each new connection I do

```
activeUsers.labels(user.name).inc();
```

My question is how can write query to Prometheus to extract DAU and MAU from `active_users` time series? How can I count incrementation of distinct `username` in 24 hours/30 days window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus isn't really the right tool for this as it's more about system-level metrics rather than those of individual requests. I'd recommend doing this via an event logging system like the ELK stack.