# Which type in Prometheus is best for DAU representation？

Tags: prometheus

DAU is always incremental throughout the day, so it looks like Counter is better and easier to calculate increments.

However, DAU is cleared again every day, so it does not satisfy the requirement of Counter.

Note: The calculation of DAU is not discussed here, DAU uses other ways to do the calculation internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation, a [Gauge](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge) is in order here as they specifically mention:

> Gauges are typically used for measured values like temperatures or current memory usage, but also "counts" that can go up and down, like the number of concurrent requests.

Also see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45128404/19238131) in a related thread. Prometheus main purpose is system / performance monitoring, less so providing usage statistics.